# About the square root in the geodesic distance

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, optimal-transport

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert} 
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Pb}{\mathbb P}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{ D}}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}
\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}} $I am currently reading about Optimal Transport. I am interested in the Otto Calculus and the corresponding Benamou Brenier Formula. I encountered a problem in my understanding. 
The Otto Calculus induces a formal (infinite dimensional) riemannian structure $g$ on a smooth manifold $M$. On the one hand the corresponding riemannian/geodesic distance is given by 
$$ d(\mu_0,\mu_1) = \inf_{\mathcal{CE}(\mu_0,\mu_1)}  \mathcal{L}(\gamma) $$
where 
$$\mathcal{L}(\gamma) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}( \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)) }\mathrm{d} t$$
denotes the length of a smooth enough curve and $\mathcal{CE}$ a set of smooth curves connecting $ \mu_0,\mu_1$. 
On the other hand we know the benamou brenier formula which says
$$W_2(\mu_0,\mu_1) = \sqrt{ \inf_{\mathcal{CE}(\mu_0,\mu_1)} \left\{ \int_{0}^{1} g_{\gamma(t)}( \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))  \dx t \right\} }.$$ 
It is stated that the riemannian/geodesic distance and the Wasserstein distance $W_2$ coincide. However the position of the square root in each expression is different. This leads to my following question.

How can one resolve the square root problem? I have seen that one can define the riemannian/geodesic distance different. See for example [here](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/014.OV-Talagrand.pdf) where 
$$ d(\mu_0,\mu_1) = \inf_{\mathcal{CE}(\mu_0,\mu_1)} \sqrt{ \int_0^1 g_{\gamma(t)}( \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t)) \mathrm{d} t}.$$
Why is this possible? Is there a relation to geodesics?

[Here](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/P12.CIME_.pdf) the named equality is stated in defintion 1.5.

PS. I think this questions is more about riemannian geometry and the associated distance than about optimal transport. Therefore i missed out on many details to narrow down my problem. However, if i am wrong please tell me and i will edit for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functional $$E[\gamma] \doteq \int_0^1 g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))\,{\rm d}t,$$perhaps with a $1/2$ multiplying factor, is called the *energy functional* associated to the metric $g$. Geodesics are precisely the critical points of $E$. Also, it follows from Cauchy-Schwarz that ${\cal L}[\gamma]^2 \leq E[\gamma]$.

If I understand it correctly, there is no problem with the square root whatsoever. The relevant result is Proposition 1.3 in your last link, which establishes the desired equality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May i ask a question about this? For me it is not clear from the proof of Proposition 1.3 that one has the equality in the case of a length space. I agree for the ineqaulity you mentioned and i understand how to conclude equality if $(X,d)$ is geodesic. But what about the converse inequality in the case of a length space? What am i missing?

Comment: I think the equality follows because the inequality they prove there will be an equality if $\gamma$ has constant speed for almost all $t$, and *every* Lipschitz curve can be reparametrized this way. Since length is invariant by reparametrization, you could consider the infimum over the collection of constant speed curves only.